# openpyxl if condition formula with reference fails

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Using python 2.7 and openpyxl, I am inserting an IF formula into excel worksheet that references fields in other sheet.

While other formulas work (CONTIF, COUTN, SUM, etc) I kind of do not find the reason for this "simple" IF formula does not to work. Only IF is the problem

This is my code

```
for i in range(0,len(sortedWorkers)):
        for a, rr in enumerate(dates):
            row_nb = i + 3
            coll = 3 + a
            clmn_letter = get_column_letter(coll + 3)
            # =IF(Worked!I$2=7;Worked!I3;"")
            valFormula = '=IF(Worked!%s$2=7;Worked!%s%s;"")' %(clmn_letter,clmn_letter, str(row_nb))
            _cl = ws12.cell(column= coll, row= row_nb, value=valFormula)
```

in the comment you can se the formula. The format is correct. It also works if I manually insert it into excel.

Also field coordinates and everything matches.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Formulas are sometimes serialised in the XML differently than they appear in the GUI. They may have prefixes, or use different words, or, and I think this may be the case here, they use different separators between parameters. In countries which use a comma as the decimal separator, semi-colons are used to separate parameters in the GUI, but the XML will use commas.

You can check this by looking at the source of a file created by Excel.

Comment: There is no formula inserted in the excel cell. I get an error that excel repaired or removed unreadable content. Like I said same formulas were going into other sheets and all worked fine. I will check on your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

So at the end the whole problem was that with using IF formula commas have to be used "," not semi-colons ";"

NB you must use the English name for a function and function arguments must be separated by commas and not other punctuation such as semi-colons.

Comment: Which is basically what I said and covered in the openpyxl documentation.

Comment: This confused me as well. Apparently the German version of Excel uses German function names and semicolons for argument separators while the English version uses English function names and commas as argument separators. This is not openpyxl's fault, since it just uses the English version of formulas as would be used in the English version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

encoutered the same kind of issue trying to insert an =IF statement in a formula.

As being said, you need to only use commas as separators and only formula implemented in openpyxl :

```
from openpyxl.utils import FORMULAE
print(FORMULAE)
```

In addition, the only way i've found making it work with IF is affecting the formula with this syntax :

worksheet[cell coords].value="IF(condition,if true, if false)

which would look like for example (working example) :

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'empty_book.xlsx'
ws1 = wb.active
ws1["A1"].value='=IF(1=1,"True","False")'
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Hope it'll help.